# How to run methods in Parallel in php without using any extension?

Tags: php, amphp

Is it possible to run two methods in parallel without using any extension like `pthread` or `pcntl`?

I tried [Symfony/Process](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html) but it seems like I can use it only for php cli programing.

My requirement is for **php web application**. I found [amphp/parallel](https://github.com/amphp/parallel) that says it works without any extension. I tried the below example. Though I don't know if the library provides true parallel functionality or something else like queuing tasks? Because it is commented below "without any extension parallel processing is not possible".

Before I try the `amphp/parallel` I wanted to be sure if the library which I found is the right one for my job. Let's say I want to run two methods test1() and test2() in parallel and use the result from those two methods in next line.

```php
    <?php

    require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    use Amp\Parallel\Worker;
    use Amp\Promise;

    $urls = [
        'https://secure.php.net',
        'https://amphp.org',
        'https://github.com',
    ];

    $promises = [];
    foreach ($urls as $url) {
        $promises[$url] = Worker\enqueueCallable('file_get_contents', $url);
    }

    $responses = Promise\wait(Promise\all($promises));

    foreach ($responses as $url => $response) {
        \printf("Read %d bytes from %s\n", \strlen($response), $url);
```

```
test1(){
   // do some database query
}

test2(){
  // run a lengthy for loop
}
```

Comment: If you found a library that does what you want, spend the time to learn it. The concept of running multiple processes in parallel requires you to have some understanding of how it works either way. We're here to help you sort out specific issues with your current code which requires you to put in the effort to make some attempts yourself first. Currently, the question is too broad.

Comment: You can't use threads without an extension.

Comment: @Olivier But in amphp/parallel  it is written it doesn't use any extension.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I updated my question a bit. Please have a look.

Comment: @SkyRar What is your target that you want to parallelly run? If you just actually want to make **concurrent** (not parallel) HTTP requests, you can achieve it via [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/) coroutines. It only requires `ext-curl` extension which is available in many hosting services.

Comment: amphp/parallel uses [ext-parallel](https://github.com/krakjoe/parallel) if available; otherwise it spawns PHP processes.

Comment: That's not even your code. That's the example code from the amphp/parallel repository. We need to see _your_ effort together with an explanation what you expect to happen and what actually happens.

Comment: @mpyw I updated the test1() and test2() methods. It is not specific to http call only. Say some time-consuming methods

Comment: @Olivier Thanks for the information. `proc_open()` + `stream_select()` loop seem to have no external dependencies.

Comment: @mpyw proc_open seems to take only cmd. But I need it to create separate process for php-fpm or apache. I mean for webserver specifically